# getting regId null while i am following fire base cloud messaging

Tags: android

I am getting null i use debugger in main class thank in advance

This my **firebaseinstanceserviceid** service

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // Saving reg id to shared preferences
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

    // sending reg id to your server
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

This is my Main Class where i use broadcast receiver for getting id kindly help me i am following the FCM documentation

```
    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };

    displayFirebaseRegId();`   private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
    else
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // register GCM registration complete receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

    // register new push message receiver
    // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

    // clear the notification area when the app is opened
    NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please recheck these steps :

1)  google-services.json

2) Check gradle dependensies

3) Check Project Gradle :

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

4) In App Gradle at the bottom :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And then try to send notification from firebase admin panel.

Note :  Put your json file in app package.

[image]

Comment: file google-services.json is missing from where i can get this file where i can put in my project ? @Babul Patel